# Print all files content in while loop with quoted

Tags: bash

I have files.txt containing list of files:

```
'/some/file.txt'
'/other_file.php'
'/third/file.txt'
```

and I want to print the content in all the files:

```
cat files.txt |while read line
do
    less $line
done
```

When I run this it says "No such file or directory"

if I run `less '/some/file.txt'` it works. Why it's not working inside the while loop?

Comment: It seems to be a path related issue. Where are your files placed? Are you giving a relative or full path?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    less "${line//\'/}"
done < files.txt
```

Comment: If the answer is helping you to find the solution, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and mark with a green hook, thx.

Comment: how can i use vi instead less? if i use it it hangs immediately.

Comment: `vi "${line//\'/}"`